how to make column readonly based on the value of another column in oracle apex
I have created editable  interactive grid in oracle apex based on employees table. In IG i have mutiple column such as ename,salary and comm. I want to make the comm column readonly based on the value of salary dynamically . For instance if the value in salary column is 2000 or less the comm column should become readonly. I have write code to achieve this functionality but code not worked as i want. let me share code with you
  var salValue = apex.region("mygrid").call.getSelectedRecords()\[0\].get("SAL");

var commColumnId = "COMM"; //          static ID or column name of the COMM column
// Get the interactive grid model

var igModel = apex.region("mygrid").call.model;
// Iterate through each row in the grid model
igModel.forEach(function(record) {
var commCell =        record.getCellValue(commColumnId);
// Check if SAL value is <= 2000
if (salValue <= 2000) {
    // Set COMM column to readonly
    commCell.attributes.readOnly = true;
} else {
    // Set COMM column to editable
    commCell.attributes.readOnly = false;
}

});
// Refresh the interactive grid to apply the changes
apex.region("mygrid").call.refresh();
first line returns the error is not a function

Add Static id of Column Salary SAL and Commission COM then Add Dynamic Action on Salary Columns that will fire on Change And Add jQuery code if ( $('#SAL').val() <= 2000 ) { $("#COM").prop('readonly', true); } else { $("#COM").prop('readonly', false); }

Add Static id of Column Salary SAL and Commission COM then Add Dynamic Action on Salary Columns  that will fire on Change And Add jQuery code
if ( $('#SAL').val() <= 2000 )
{
$("#COM").prop('readonly', true);
}
else
{
$("#COM").prop('readonly', false);
}
